# How Keyboards communicate with Computer?

Tags: arduino, keyboard, communication, i2c, spi

I'm wondering that how keyboard and computer communicate?USB has 4 cable which are Voltage , Ground , Data+ and Data-.Is computer communicate with keyboard with I2C , SPI or such communication protocols?Could we read the data's with arduino like microprocessors?For example if I push the 'E' then can I read this data with arduino like 0x0062 or something like that?

Comment: it is USB HID protocol. you can read it with USB Host Shield. or you can attach a PS2 keyboard to Arduino. most USB keyboards work as PS2 over USB to PS2 adapter. there is an Arduino library for PS2 keyboard. It is what I read. I never tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard works with Computer using USB interface which has 4 lines (+5V, D+, D-, Ground).
Keyboard works in device mode where as Computer works in Host mode. So when you connect USB keyboard (first time) to the Computer then Computer starts understanding it and recognized as USB Keyboard and Keyboard gets power from Computer.
And when you press any key on keyboard then keycodes are sent to Computer. 
Each key on the keyboard having keycode defined.